# Read Websphere Liberty bootstrap.properties at faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, websphere-liberty, properties-file, faces-config

Is there an way to read the Websphere Liberty bootstrap.properties through the faces-config.xml on java server faces tier ?

My application is being populate a couple of variables statically at faces-config but we would like to use the external file from Liberty properties in order to modify those variables and use they at faces-config.xml as example below, but when the web app is running the variables are not being renderized:

bootstrap.properties:

```
bootstrap.csc.ds.serverproviders=PRODUCTION 9.4;https://0.0.000.000:31116/twsd/
```

jsf faces-config.xml:

```
<value>"${bootstrap.csc.ds.serverproviders}"</value>
```